# native button widget background color

Tags: livecode

from the tools palette I inserted the android native button widget, how can I change the background color?

in the propety inspector it is possible to change only the color of the text.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The LiveCode forum is a great place to get your questions answered. That said, if you need to change the background color of a button, you may need to reproduce an Android looking button by using a regular LC push button. Think UI design from scratch. It isn't really that difficult to emulate a Material Design button.

There is an interesting LC forum discussion with some varied techniques for Android Buttons here:
[Styling Android Buttons in LiveCode](https://forums.livecode.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=32304&p=177463&hilit=button%20background#p177463)